# Cone shaped train wheels

Tags: rail, wheels

I was watching [this Feynman video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAwDvbIfkos) and (as usual) his explanations make a lot of sense.

Now I just took a train, and am not so sure anymore. Looking at the train wheels they did not appear cone shaped to me. Also, if the train was running on cone shaped wheels I would expect that there is very little contact area between the wheel and the rails. However the rails looked completely shiny on the top suggesting that the wheels are in contact with all of the rail (i.e. flat wheels).

Are modern trains using a different method to deal with this problem or are the cones almost flat anyway (what angle)?

Comment: Have you looked for any wheel dimensions or specifications or just go with the video?

Comment: Also, the top of the rail is not flat.

Comment: @hazzey: if the top of the rail is not flat and the wheels are cone shaped (as some pictures I saw confirm), why doesn't this  create the same kind of problems on straight line tracks that you were trying to avoid in curves?

Comment: Because the equilibrium operating point is different. Symmetric on straight track, asymmetric around a curve. The more cone angle, the tighter the corner possible, but the lower the speed before sway instability sets in.

Comment: Make some measurements (or look up same) of the actual shape of rails and train wheels.  You'll see your assumptions are mostly wrong.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Which of my assumptions are wrong?

Comment: "not cone shaped" ,  "little contact..."

Comment: the issue here is likely the actual cone angle is less than what you may have seen in various cartoon diagrams.